# Responsive Sider with Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

To start with, it may help to watch this video explaining what I would like to do:  https://www.loom.com/share/1447f9a8d5ea44b18d6e39a6ea65c469

With that said, here is a written explanation:

The Ant Design Layout component can be used to create a togglable sidebar -- as shown here in the docs:  https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-custom-trigger

That same sidebar can be made responsive -- as shown here in the docs:  https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-responsive

I have combined those two features together and have created a responsive, toggleable sidebar.  In my particular configuration, the sidebar shrinks down to 80px when it gets below a width of 1200px.

This all works fine.

What I would like to now do is set a second breakpoint (in my case at the `md` breakpoint of 768px).  At that breakpoint, I want the sidebar to shrink down to 0 pixels, but still be toggleable via the trigger icon in the header.

Any ideas on how can I set up that second breakpoint using Ant Design?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?